# Qt equivalence to controllers in C# or generalization of gui elements

Tags: c++, qt

In C# there are controllers which takes a GUI element and everything in it to be able to use in multiple places at the same time, does Qt have the same thing?

In my case I have various Groupboxes with with textEdits which I need to fill depending on some options. Currently I tried a QStackedWidget but the contents cant have the same objectname so it I cant fill the textEdits as easily.

How should I go about to generalize it?

Answer (score 0):

in qt the same, you can always "move" widgets from one layout to another,
and if you are using qt creator, then widgets in editor are inserted in the ui so you can always have access to them by its name..

for example:

```
namespace Ui
{
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
```

you will have some private member `Ui::MainWindow* ui{nullptr};` and there you can get the labels you inserted in the main window doing:

```
ui->myLabel->setText(.....
or
ui->myButton->setEnable(....
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that I was asking.

Comment: quoting OP: "***...does Qt have the same thing?***"